# Nginx server timeout connecting to docker

Tags: docker, owncloud, onlyoffice

I'm currently trying to install a docker image of owncloud integrated with onlyoffice document server according to https://www.linuxbabe.com/docker/onlyoffice-nextcloud-integration-docker

However, whenever I go to the ip address I get "504 Gateway Time-out" from the nginx server.

According to the logs from the Docker container:

2017/12/14 22:30:45 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "onlyoffice-document-server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:94

The logs from the onlyoffice container don't indicate anything went wrong.
Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the documentserver container has been created but there was an issue when starting it.
Please create a new issue in the [docker-onlyoffice-owncloud/issues](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/docker-onlyoffice-owncloud/issues)

What changes were made in the default nginx.conf ?